# How can i check how many markers are in my Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any function which can count how many markers are in my map?

**Code :**

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng);
```

which adds unlimited markers using a setOnMapLongClickListener and i want to limit only by two

For example in **pseudocode:**

```
     if(marker.count()<2){
     //add a marker
        }else{
 Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"You can only have 2 markers",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the solution
You create an ArrayList, in this arraylist you add all your markers

```
final ArrayList<Marker> markers =new ArrayList<>();


 if (markers.size()<2){
                      markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                              .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())
                              ) .position(latLng)));
                      mMap.addPolyline(polys
                              .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).add(latLng));
                              points.add(latLng);


                  }else{
                      Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "You Can Only Add 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
```